# Unresolved Dependency in Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Can anyone tell me please what's wrong with my dependency Hamcrest in Maven?
That's a pity but I can't attach screenshot here.

The screenshot from [IntelliJ IDEA](http://s27.postimg.org/sor4mpl77/X2g_Ds.png)

One the right side one can see that the dependency hamcrest-all:1.3 is inside dependency junit:4.11.

Maybe something wrong with my pom.xml file?

There is also a problem with hamcrest version 1.3 - dependency hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3 not found.

When I try to update Maven indices, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a slight difference between the group ids. Notice in the maven repository group id is org.hamcrest

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works!
Pity that I can't vote for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, not specifying the dependency's version can give this Error

```
Unresolved Dependency
```

just specify the version of the dependency

example:

instead of this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

use this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```